# Eclipse MemoryAnalyzer and sdkman

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, eclipse-memory-analyzer, sdkman

I am trying to run Eclipse MemoryAnalyzer on my Mac 10.13.6 (High Siena). When I start it, I get a message that reads

> To open "MemoryAnalyzer" you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime

There are several mentions of that on StackOverflow, but none of the suggested fixes work:

- I have added

```
    -vm
    /Users/myuser/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java
```

to MemoryAnalyzer.ini. Still the same problem.

- I have added

  `<string>-vm</string><string>/Users/myuser/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java</string>`

to Info.plist. Still the same problem.

- There is a /usr/bin/java, which is a symlink to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java. This is somewhat strange, as some people say it should be a symlink to /Users/myuser/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java. This may be a hint on a broken sdkman installation, but `java --version` behaves as expected, changing the version via `sdk u java ...` works as expected.

What else could I try?

Comment: Have you checked [this post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=198527&goto=1754167&#msg_1754167) on the eclipse forums?

Comment: The post advices to change Eclipse.ini, which I did. For MemoryAnalyzer only installations, Eclipse.ini == MemoryAnalyzer.ini

Answer (score 0):

To save someone some searching later, this worked for me:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Using_a_JDK_without_macOS_directory_layout

Using SDKMAN! 8.0.282.hs-adpt, setting for me was:

```
$ cat /Applications/mat.app/Contents/Info.plist | grep sdk
            <string>-vm</string><string>/Users/[removed]/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.282.hs-adpt/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib</string>
```